# How do I activate the Emmet plugin in Atom for PHP files

Tags: php, atom-editor

Simple question, but couldn't find it nowhere. 
By default on Atom, the Emmet plugin only works for HTML, CSS, LESS and SCSS files. But it should also work on PHP files. 
How does one enable it for .php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please install emmet-snippets-compatibility

Refer Link: https://atom.io/packages/emmet-snippets-compatibility

I haven't tested yet.